# How to make a partition invisible?

Tags: partitioning

I have 2 HDDs. One with Ubuntu and one with win7. The win7 disk has 3 partitions of which
I want to make the boot partition with win7 on make invisible for Ubuntu.

When I make it hidden in gparted my win7 does not boot anymore. Can I make it invisible for Ubuntu but bootable.

Comment: This is easily doable but I'll need to see a print out of your /etc/fstab from Ubuntu. Post that up and I can help.

Basically, you'll need to find out the `BLKID` of the NTFS partition. And the on a line in your /etc/fstab you'll make that particular `BLKID` 'noauto'.

Comment: That will make Nautilus show the partition icon, so you can double-click to mount it, right? Guess it wont help too much.

Answer (score 1):

Install NTFS configuration tool and Mount Manager from Software center. U can check and uncheck wanted partition from Mount manager and NTFS C tool. Invisibe i Understand Unmount.